# Get Access DB filename with FileOpenDialog then run query against table within it?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, fileopendialog

I want to browse/select a database file through an Access form and run a query on it based on the file path of the selected database file. I have tried like this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM ExternalTableName IN '[Forms]![MyForm]![SelectedFilePath]'
    WHERE Condition
```

...but that didn't work however this SQL did work:

```
SELECT *
    FROM ExternalTableName IN 'C:\users\desktop\filename.mdb'
    WHERE Condition
```

For browsing the file, I used this VBA snippet:

```
Private Sub cmd1()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim oFD As Variant
    Dim fileName As String

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Access Files", "*.mdb", 1
        .Title = "Choose Text File"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        .Show

        For Each oFD In .SelectedItems
            fileName = oFD
        Next oFD
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    '~~> Change this to the relevant TextBox
    Me.TextFieldName = fileName

    Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: So you have the answer?  examples #2 and #3 worked?  (You can run a query on an external database using linked tables, but the data is still going to be processed by your database unless you have the data on a server (ie., SQL Server)....  Some application needs to handle the processing,)

Comment: The 2nd Code worked. But I want it to be more user friendly by attaching the file by file dialogue.

Comment: Is it really an `MDB` that you're opening (not an `ACCDB`?)

Comment: See the code below.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

To query a table located in an `MDB` that the user selects from a *File Open* dialog, the simplest way (while avoiding additional References) is like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub testQueryExternalTable()
'displays RecordCount from specified table, selected database
    Const tableName = "tblLog"
    Const defaultPath = "c:\users\" 'default path OR path+filename
    Dim rs As Recordset, fName As String, sql as String

    fName = getFileOpenDialog(defaultPath) 'get filename
    If fName = "" Then MsgBox "You clicked cancel!": Exit Sub

    sql = "select * from " & tableName & " in '" & fName & "'"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( sql ) 'query the table
    With rs
        .MoveLast 'count records
        MsgBox .RecordCount & " records found"
        .Close 'close recordset
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing 'always clean up objects when finished
End Sub

Function getFileOpenDialog(defaultPath As String) As String
'returns filename selected from dialog ("" if user Cancels)
    With Application.FileDialog(3)
        .Title = "Please select a database to query" 'set caption
        .InitialFileName = defaultPath 'default path OR path+filename
        .AllowMultiSelect = False 'maximum one selection
        .Filters.Clear 'set file filters for drop down
        .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*" '(in reverse order)
        .Filters.Add "Access Databases", "*.mdb" '(last = default filter)
        If .Show = True Then getFileOpenDialog = .SelectedItems(1) 'show dialog
    End With
End Function
```

---

## More Information:

- MSDN : [**Application.FileDialog Property** (Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-filedialog-property-access)
- MSDN : [**FileDialog.InitialFileName Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210656(v=office.11).aspx)
- MSDN : [**Accessing External Data with MS Access**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722917.aspx)
- MSDN : [**Database.OpenRecordset Method** (DAO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx)

---

***Original Answer:***

It's easier (and more efficient) to use Access's built-in functionality rather than recreating it in VBA.

<sub><sup>(Click to enlarge images)</sup></sub>
 [image: screenshot]  [image: screenshot]

The *first option imports*, and **the seconds option *emphasized text*links** without importing.  Once the table is linked you can work with it in VBA or queries as if it's a local table.